# alfresco unable to start

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Just installing a brand new alfresco and the share application is able to start but the alfresco repo doesn't. I get the following error in the BE:

```
PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 02080001 Keystores are invalid
    at org.alfresco.encryption.EncryptionChecker$1.execute(EncryptionChecker.java:71
........

Caused by: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 02080000 Failed to create key: metadata
 in key store: 
   Location: /srv/alfresco/alf_data/keystore/keystore
   Provider: null
   Type:     JCEKS
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.createKey(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:644)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.validateKeys(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:890)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.validateKeys(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:187)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.KeyStoreChecker.validateKeyStores(KeyStoreChecker.java:47)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.EncryptionChecker$1.execute(EncryptionChecker.java:66)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.getSecretKey(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:755)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.createKey(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:633)
    ... 32 more
```

I am unsure as to why this is happening.

Comment: Are you sure that the user running alfresco has the rights to read/write the `keystore` file mentioned in the stack trace?

Comment: How did you install Alfresco?

Comment: Doing a custom install. Component by component. I'm installing it into Tomcat 7 following this: http://paultiseo.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/installing-alfresco-community-4-on-ubuntu-server-12/ and the wiki texts

Comment: Then you'll need to create your keystores, because they aren't present. Or you could rather copy the keystores created through the installer/zip.

Comment: Do the keystores have to be conform to a certain name conventions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your replies. In the end the only thing that worked was copying the keystore folder under the expanded war to the custom directory. Nothing else would work.

Comment: From which folder did you copy it?

Comment: @Teysz it's under your ${dir.root}/keystore

Comment: and where did you copy it? which is the custom folder?

Comment: @akshit It's been a long time ago now so I guess I copied it from the directory under the expanded war to where my alf_data is located

Answer (score 3):

In recent version, the keystore is now stored in the war, in the classpath, not in alf_data. The default value in now:
dir.keystore=classpath:alfresco/keystore

So just comment the line dir.keystore in your alfresco-global.properties and it should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

I want you to delete both **alf_data** and your **alfresco database** and recreate again.

Both of them are synchronized with each other as alf_data stores bin files whose location are saved in database.

And check these setting are correctly defined in alfresco-global.properties.

---

**To keep keystore**

If you want to keep keystore after deleting them, you can keep it anywhere apart from alf_data. I mean if you remove keystore location

```
dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore
```

from `alfresco-global.properties`.

Keystore will be created under ***default keystores location*** `dir.keystore=classpath:alfresco/keystore` which is defined in `repository.properties` under `<apache-tomcat>\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco`.

Comment: But I'd still need to create keystores after deleting them.

Comment: I added explanation for keeping apart of keystore from alf_data. Hope it will help!!!

Comment: Only just got around to doing this today. but I borrowed and made a few changes to the generate keystores script (just file path changes) and ran it. the keystores are created fine but I still get the same error. deleting db and alf_data doesn't help.

Comment: should mention that I got around this by commenting out the keystore location in alfresco-global.properties. I have tried again adapting the generate_keystores.sh script then running it after deleting the db and directories. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting `/srv/alfresco/alf_data` directory and recreate it again. Then create `/srv/alfresco/alf_data` - and make sure tomcat/java can use it (`sudo chown tomcat7:tomcat7 /srv/alfresco/alf_data` if you followed that tutorial to the letter).

Alternatively, you can put `dir.root` directive in `<TOMCAT_HOME>/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties` file and place alf_data elsewhere.